# silverlight 4.0 scrollviewer not updating

Tags: silverlight-4.0, scrollviewer

I am new to Silverlight. I am trying to provide a zoom in functionality along with inkpresenter. I am using Silverlight 4, c#, asp.net. I can bind the slider to canvas and it does zoom in but i am facing problem with the scrollviewer layout which is not updating. there are allot of post that mentioned that i need to used layout transform. Can any one please let me know what i am doing wrong or any other suggestion.

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="2" Minimum="0" Value="1" Width="100"/>
</StackPanel>

<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollBar"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,1,1,1" Grid.Row="1">
    <ScrollViewer.Content>
        <toolkit:LayoutTransformer Name="TheTransformer" Background="{x:Null}">
            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform  x:Name="contentScale" ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider,Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider,Path=Value}" />
            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>

            <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.Content>
                <Canvas x:Name="cnsImageEditable" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" OpacityMask="#FFE89E9E">

                    <!--The following commented bit does work i can zoomin and out but scroller not updating -->                
                    <!--<Canvas.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider,Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider,Path=Value}"/>
                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>-->

                <InkPresenter x:Name="inkCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image x:Name="imgEditableImage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Image>
                </InkPresenter>

                </Canvas>
            </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.Content>
        </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
    </ScrollViewer.Content>
</ScrollViewer>
```

any help is much appretiated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899729/layouttransformer-in-silverlight-not-working , worked for me. Specifically:

> I found that Transforms in silverlight happens after Layout, so I changed the CanvasWidth property only once till the scrollbars show, and then zooming would work perfectly,